# Java URL: Get root of URL object (remove path)

Tags: java

Is there any way to get only the scheme + host + port from a given `URL`.

So I mean, I want to remove path url segment.

```
URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                       + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
```

I've been playing with this:

```
System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());
```

Output is:

```
protocol = http
authority = example.com:80
host = example.com
port = 80
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
query = name=networking
filename = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
ref = DOWNLOADING
```

what I want to get is a new `URL` object to `http://example.com:8080`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found shorter method that maintains everything but the path portion, use `URI.resolve()`.

```java
// For java.net.URI
URI uri = URI.create("http://example.com:8081/api/test");
System.out.println(uri) // prints "http://example.com:8081/api/test"

URI uriNoPath = uri.resolve("/");
System.out.println(uriNoPath) // prints "http://example.com:8081/"


// For java.net.URL, convert to URI first and then back to URL
URL url = new URL("http://example.com:8081/api/test");
URL urlNoPath = url.toURI().resolve("/").toURL();
System.out.println(urlNoPath); // prints "http://example.com:8081/"
```

Comment: Are you importing from `java.net.URL`? I'm Getting symbol resolve not found. I don't see the method on oracle docs either.

Comment: @SumitWadhwa The code was incorrectly using a java.net.URL, when `resolve` is only available java.net.URI. I've updated the example code.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `URL` constructor to build a new URL.

```java
URL newUrl = new URL(aURL.getProtocol(), aURL.getHost(), 8080, "/");
```

Comment: I would assume the OP is looking for a single method of the url that will do that without having to specify the host, port and slash explicitly.